# Ожидание результата EditText в цикле for

Tags: java, android

Есть ArrayList в котором находятся слова. Есть EditText куда пользователь вписывает это же слово. Есть цикл for, который должен проходить по каждому элементу Листа и сравнивать его с написанным вручную с поля EditText. Вопрос: как сделать так, что бы в цикл ожидал пока пользователь напишет ответ в поле EditText?

Comment: здесь не нужен цикл. на поля ввода нужно поставить слушатели, к каждому слушателю прикрепить "свой" элемент листа и сравнивать его с полученным вводом. Код можно упростить, написав один слушатель, который будет, например, по id виджета, который его вызвал читать соответствующий элемент листа и сравнивать

Answer (score 0):

1. Хороший вариант сделать это на RxJava https://habr.com/ru/post/345278/
2. Можно также вешать слушатель addTextChangedListener на editText  как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309710/how-to-apply-the-textchange-event-on-edittext и реализовать задержку, например, через handler.postDelay, удаляя предыдущий вызов handler'a